# Convert JSON String to Object with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

A service method returns `response()->json($response)`

And the response from the endpoints is

```
{"units":[{"id":1,"unit_name":"Carton","created_at":"2023-04-28T16:25:24.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-04-28T16:25:24.000000Z"},{"id":2,"unit_name":"Box","created_at":"2023-04-28T16:25:31.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-04-28T16:25:31.000000Z"},{"id":3,"unit_name":"Kg","created_at":"2023-04-28T16:25:39.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-04-28T16:25:39.000000Z"}],"loc":"Loc","success":1}
```

I want to Parse this JSON String to Object in Android Java. Here is my code: Please I can't get a UnitRes object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
                UnitRes res = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<UnitRes>(){}.getType());
```

Please what is wrong here??

```
public class UnitRes{
    private List<Unit> units;
    private int success;
    private String loc;
}
public class Unit{
    private int id;
    private String unit_name;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the `response` in your current code, and I assume that it would be the content of your JSON file. You may use `gson.fromJson(response, UnitRes.class)` to parse the file, which is demonstrated as follows:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static final String JSON_FILENAME = "src/main/resources/data.json";
    // the path and filename to JSON file

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(JSON_FILENAME));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            builder.append(scanner.next()); // read the content of the JSON file
        }
        String response = builder.toString(); // get the string of the content

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        UnitRes res = gson.fromJson(response, UnitRes.class);
        // public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws ... { ... }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Note: the version of GSON that I use:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```